# Ms access Run time error 2471 only if there is letter in the text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using this

```
If DCount("[ITEMCODE]", "LOCALTEMPORARYIMPORTS", "[itemcode]= '" & Me![ITEMCODE2] & "' AND [INVOICENUMBER] like " & Me.INVOICENUMBER) > 0 Then
```

to check in  "localtemporaryimports" table if "itemcode" and "invoicenumber" already exist.

if "invoicenumber" has letter i get the error. And if i remove the letter everything is working fine.
What i'm i missing?
using office 365

Comment: Missing input validation? Don't run this (or any) query without first validating the inputs!

Comment: Why use `LIKE` without wildcards? Use `=` instead. And if `INVOICENUMBER` is a text field, enclose it with quotes like you did other parameter. If it is always a number (which you can't use `LIKE`), validate user input for that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As you look for an exact invoice number that is text, filter as you do for the itemcode:

```
If DCount("[ITEMCODE]", "LOCALTEMPORARYIMPORTS", "[itemcode]= '" & Me![ITEMCODE2] & "' AND [INVOICENUMBER] = '" & Me!INVOICENUMBER & "'") > 0 Then
```

However, as you don't need to count a unique value, use `DLookup`:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("[ITEMCODE]", "LOCALTEMPORARYIMPORTS", "[itemcode]= '" & Me![ITEMCODE2] & "' AND [INVOICENUMBER] = '" & Me!INVOICENUMBER & "'")) Then
```

Comment: Dlookup worked fine, thanks for your help

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.